# Proving equation with binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 C^i_n = n(n+1) \cdot 2^{n-2}$$
I could use some help with proving that this equation stands. Should I try to use mathematical induction?

Comment: What is $C^i_n$?

Comment: I can also write it as $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 C^i_n =\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n!i^2}{i!(n-i)!}$

Comment: @doppz. It's $n \choose i$. This notation was heavily used in France till recently (and it's still, alive), and probably in other countries as well. May I add it's the one I prefer ? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a fairly nice direct combinatorial proof.  Rewrite the right hand side as $n(n-1)2^{n-2}+n2^{n-1}$ and observe that both sides answer the following question:  "From a group of $n$ people, in how many ways can one choose a committee together with a president and secretary in the committee, who may or may not be the same person?"

Answer (score 1):

Write:

$$(1+x)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n C_n^i x^i$$

Differentiate:

$$n(1+x)^{n-1} = \sum_{i=1}^n i C_n^i  x^{i-1}$$

Multiply by $x$:

$$nx(1+x)^{n-1} = \sum_{i=1}^n i C_n^i  x^{i}$$

$$n\left((1+x)^{n}-(1+x)^{n-1}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n i C_n^i  x^{i}$$

Differentiate again:

$$n\left(n(1+x)^{n-1}-(n-1)(1+x)^{n-2}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n i^2 C_n^i  x^{i-1}$$

Now let $x=1$:

$$n\left(n2^{n-1}-(n-1)2^{n-2}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 C_n^i  $$

$$n^22^{n-1}-n(n-1)2^{n-2}=\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 C_n^i  $$

$$2^{n-2}\left(2n^2-n(n-1)\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 C_n^i  $$

$$n(n+1)2^{n-2}=\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 C_n^i  $$